# Upgrading from Angular 5.2 to 6

Tags: angular

I tried to upgrade my project fron Angular 5.2 to 6 using the instructions at https://update.angular.io/

After upgrade, when I build the project (`ng build`), I keep getting below error

```
/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
```

I referred to the observable in my code as

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
```

Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Make sure that you’re using rxjs 6 in your project. You may also want to import Observable from ˋrxjs/Observable` so you won’t import the whole library.

Answer (score 0):

That should be all you need to do for the Observable class, but the error message strongly suggests you haven't updated all the import paths. I would double check to see if you forgot one, because

```
/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"
```

Means its still looking in 'rxjs/Observable' which was the old import path

Answer (score 0):

I use this in 6.4

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
```

version

```
  "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
  "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
```